# Set inline-svg as the background of a div

Tags: html, css, containers, inline-svg

I got a place on my CSS Grid where I am inserting a paragraph of about 15 characters long, I would like to add a background element to it and I want it to have some personality so am using a inline SVG content.

I tried to place it at the `bottom` with a `position:relative` but when you change the view-port size it doesn't scale well. I wrapped the SVG code in a container:

```
.marquee-container {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
}
```

And the styles of the SVG:

```
.svg-marquee {
    fill: teal;
    stroke-width: 4;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

This is the HTML Markup

```
<div class="home-works">
    <div class="head">
        <h1>Entries</h1>
    </div>
    <img class="thumbnail" src="img/profile-picture.png" width="100%"/>
    <div class="main-content">                
        <div class="marquee-container">
            <svg version="1.1"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
                        x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 634 175" style="enable-background:new 0 0 634 175;"
                        xml:space="preserve">
                            <path class="svg-marquee" d="M595.9,173C317,173,317,153,38.1,153C27.3,153,2,157.6,2,151C2,87.5,34.8,87.5,34.8,24c0-6.6-7.5-22,3.3-22
                            C317,2,317,22,595.9,22c10.8,0,36.1-4.6,36.1,2c0,63.5-32.8,63.5-32.8,127C599.2,157.6,606.7,173,595.9,173z"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <h3>title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore placeat
                                maiores ad ullam illo, blanditiis ipsam libero! Aspernatur, mollitia suscipit?
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My item is inside a CSS Grid Layout where `post` is the class I am using to style the contents of the paragraph. Which is not inside any `grid-template-areas`, its just a class within an area already defined.

```
.post {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

So the scaling doesn't go well, I would like to place the element at the background of the paragraph to be contained, what is the best approach?

```css
.marquee-container {
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
}

.svg-marquee {
  fill: teal;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}

.post {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-works">

  <div class="head">
    <h1>Entries</h1>
  </div>
  <img class="thumbnail" src="img/profile-picture.png" width="100%" />
  <div class="main-content">

    <div class="marquee-container">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 634 175" style="enable-background:new 0 0 634 175;" xml:space="preserve">
                            <path class="svg-marquee" d="M595.9,173C317,173,317,153,38.1,153C27.3,153,2,157.6,2,151C2,87.5,34.8,87.5,34.8,24c0-6.6-7.5-22,3.3-22
                            C317,2,317,22,595.9,22c10.8,0,36.1-4.6,36.1,2c0,63.5-32.8,63.5-32.8,127C599.2,157.6,606.7,173,595.9,173z"/>
                    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h3>title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore placeat maiores ad ullam illo, blanditiis ipsam libero! Aspernatur, mollitia suscipit?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isnt there any parent with relative position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are positioning the `.marquee-container` absolutely.
You need a parent to have position set to `relative`, So, add `position: relative` on the parent `.main-content`.

I don't understand why you set the `.marquee-container` height to `0`.
I would suggest set it's `height` to `auto` and have a `bottom: 0;`, (As you wanted it to be aligned to bottom of the container).

Set the `width` to `100%` since you want it to be scalable. also add a negative `z-index` so that the element doesn't cover up the contents.

Check the snippet below.

```css
.main-content {
  position: relative;
}
.marquee-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -5;
}

.svg-marquee {
  fill: teal;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}

.post {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-works">

  <div class="head">
    <h1>Entries</h1>
  </div>
  <img class="thumbnail" src="img/profile-picture.png" width="100%" />
  <div class="main-content">

    <div class="marquee-container">
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 634 175" style="enable-background:new 0 0 634 175;" xml:space="preserve">
                            <path class="svg-marquee" d="M595.9,173C317,173,317,153,38.1,153C27.3,153,2,157.6,2,151C2,87.5,34.8,87.5,34.8,24c0-6.6-7.5-22,3.3-22
                            C317,2,317,22,595.9,22c10.8,0,36.1-4.6,36.1,2c0,63.5-32.8,63.5-32.8,127C599.2,157.6,606.7,173,595.9,173z"/>
                    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
      <h3>title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore placeat maiores ad ullam illo, blanditiis ipsam libero! Aspernatur, mollitia suscipit?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your output made me reflect on the positioning on my elements I had completely forgotten about. Making it this way kind of helped me understand better the relations between, so talking about the svg element here, and by making it have an absolute position would then make it to remain inside the main-content area, correct?

Comment: as long as the `.main-content` has a `position: relative;` correct

Comment: Also, if this was what you were looking for, feel free the accept the answer :)